# Is there a point where trying to perform "Tough" alchemy is impossible?

Tags: atelier-totori-plus

in *Atelier Rorona Plus* you got a % to show you the success rate of the alchemy and you saw the modifier for traits like Success, Beginner or Complex. so with the Dragon Hourglasses so long as the final Success % was not 0 you could succeed with enough reloads (ie. True Dragon Hourglass at Alchemy Level 50 and not enough Max MP to make it was 0% until using a Beginner or Success Trait).

in *Atelier Totori Plus* you don't have a % but just a word. i was at Alchemy Level 16 when i tried to make some Tanbeash but kept failing. after a bit i was on Alchemy Level 21 and was able to make it after a couple of reloads. both times it said it was "Tough" and i know Tanbeash was level 35

So i am wondering, in the difference between Alchemy Level and an item's level, is there a point where trying to perform "Tough" alchemy is impossible? (equal to a success of 0% in Rorona)